# What's the difference between Handlebars helpers and Ember Handlebars helpers?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I can't catch up with all those changes done to plain Handlebars and modified Ember Handlebars helpers. If I remember correctly you can register a helper with the following methods

- Ember.Handlebars.helper
- Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper
- Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper
- Handlebars.registerHelper

That's too much for me. Could you explain it down to earth what's the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` is a basic helper that does not bind the argument string to a property. For instance, consider a `hello` helper created with `registerHelper` that just returns a greeting message.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('hello', function(name) {
  return 'Hello ' + name;
});
```

When you use it in a template,

```
{{hello name}}
```

You will get the display text as, `Hello name`. The value of the `name` property is **not** looked up.

To get the value of the `name` property into the helper you need, `registerBoundHelper`. As the name suggests it creates a binding between to the `name` property. Anytime the `name` changes the helper is called again to rerender. The implementation is similar,

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('hello', function(name) {
  return 'Hello ' + name;
});
```

The `Ember.Handlebars.helper` is same as `registerBoundHelper` with some additional checks to autodetect what kind of helper you want.

The vanilla `Handlebars.registerHelper` isn't used within Ember. It would create similar helpers for projects not using Ember.

Comment: Thank you! Dear Darshan, could you have a look at my another question concerning helpers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005111/custom-handlebars-helper-parameter-is-not-resolved I have a problem with a block one.

Answer (score 1):

- `Ember.Handlebars.helper` should be used by to register helpers, other methods are just limited versions of it. `Ember.Handlebars.helper` renders HTML with bindings that keep views and models in sync. Functions, Views and Components can be supplied as helper definitions.
- `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` is just like `Ember.Handlebars.helper`, but you can supply only a Function as a helper definition.
- `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` previously delegated to `Handlebars.registerHelper`. `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` no longer exists, but `Handlebars.registerHelper` is still used internally by `Ember` to create all the helpers after the bindings are set up.